# Python как сделать что бы импортированный файл видел присвоеное значение?

Tags: python

Есть два файла
test и test1.
В test есть код:

```
from test1 import*
n=1
print(mp)
```

Во втором:

```
def mp():
    print(n)
mp()
```

В test ошибка:
name 'n' is not defined.
Как исправить? И почему она возникла?

Comment: Вы прочитали текст ошибки?

Comment: Ой, виноват. Исправил

Comment: опишите проблему более полно. Почему бы не сделать функцию с параметром в этом случае? Какой смысл вы вкладываете в оператор print(mp) ? вам выдадут параметры объекта функция. а не результат ее выполнения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не выйдет. test1 выполняется в момент импорта и не видит `n`, которая инициализируется после импорта.

Он не увидит её, даже если сделать импорт после

```
n=1
from test1 import *
```

т.к. глобальные переменные видны только внутри модуля.

Можно попытаться задать переменную для конкретного модуля

```
import test1
test1.n=1
```

Но проблема в том, что для доступа к модулю всё равно нужно его импортировать до установки значения, а значит будет ошибка.

Вариантом остаётся установка переменной окружения, которая будет доступна между модулями.

test:

```
import os
os.environ['n'] = '1'
from test1 import*
```

test1:

```
import os

def mp():
    print(os.environ['n'])
mp()
```

Comment: А как тогда?) Или нет других вариантов?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ. Скорее всего, вы делаете что-то неправильно, если у вас возникла эта проблема. Лучше будет, если вы опишете в вопросе задачу,  которую решаете.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!:)